# Black screen after installing Arch Linux, conventional fixes don't work

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, grub2, laptop, amd

I recently installed Arch Linux on my HP Pavilion dv6 (Radeon HD 6770m graphics card) to dual boot with Windows 7 by following the beginner's guide found on the Arch wiki. After grub loads, I choose "Arch Linux", but nothing is displayed on the screen. A quick Google search revealed that appending `nomodeset` or `radeon.modeset=0` to the `linux` command in grub might fix the problem, but it does not appear to change anything. The line I'm using to load the kernel is

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=<UUID> rw nomodeset
```

Comment: [Add the radeon module to your initrd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KMS#Early_KMS_start) and regenerate it...

Comment: And don't forget to change `vmlinuz-linix` into `vmlinuz-linux`

Comment: @jasonwryan I did that with `mkinitpcio -p linux`, same problem.

Comment: I also tried to make a `radeon.conf` file in `/etc/modules-load.d/` according to its man page with no avail.

Comment: Can you see a TTY with `crtl-alt-F1`? How quickly do you lose the display?

Comment: No, I cant. I lose the display immediately after grub does its thing.

Comment: Have you tried using another bootloader i.e. syslinux instead of grub? Just to make sure it's not about grub. I have never succeeded at booting Arch on grub on my older PC.